# IE7 and IE8 problems on my jquery accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

i have a problem on my site one of its page is not working on ie7 and ie8 but working with other browsers, returning this error
"Unexpected call to method or property access"
 im using jquery-1.8.3
This is my code:
 my view...

```
@model SmartTimers.Models.AccountEdit
@{

    ViewBag.Title = "AccountEdit";
    string userName = ViewBag.userName;
    //Guid userId = ViewBag.userId;
    int buttonid1 = 1;
    int buttonid2 = 2;
    var buttonId = ViewBag.buttonId;
}

<div id="page-content">
    <div class="container">
<h2>
    Account Settings</h2>

        User Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;@Membership.GetUser()
        <div>
            <div id="accordion">
               &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" value="Edit User Name" 
            class = "btn btn-default" id="open-profile-Username" />
                <div style="padding: 0 30px 0 30px">

                    <h2>    
                        Edit User Name</h2>
                    <p>
                        Use the form below to change your User Name.
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Your Email Address will be use as your User Name also.
                    </p>

                    @using (Html.BeginForm("AccountEdit", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { buttonid = buttonid1, id="editUserName" }))
                    {
                        if (buttonId == 1)
                        {

                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "User Name change was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.")
                        }
                        <input type="hidden" id="buttonid" name="buttonid" value="@buttonid1" />
                        <div>
                            <fieldset>
                                <legend>User Name Edit</legend>
                                <div class="editor-label">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
                                </div>
                                <div class="editor-field">
                                    @userName
                                </div>
                                <div class="editor-label">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NewUserName)
                                </div>
                                <div class="editor-field">
                                    <input type="text" id="email" name="Email" class="validate[required,custom[email]] inputLong"
                                        value="" />
                                </div>
                                <p>
                                    <input type="submit" value="Update User Name / Email Address" class="userNameChange btn btn-default" />
                                    <a class="close-profile-Username" href="">Cancel</a>
                                </p>
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>

                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" value="Change Password" class ="btn btn-default"
                    id="open-profile-Password" />
                <div style="padding: 0 30px 0 30px">
                    <h2>
                        Change Password</h2>
                    <p>
                        Use the form below to change your password.
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        New passwords are required to be a minimum of @Membership.MinRequiredPasswordLength
                        characters in length.
                    </p>

                    @using (Html.BeginForm("AccountEdit", "Account", new { buttonid = buttonid2 }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "passwordChangeForm" }))
                    {
                        if (buttonId == 2)
                        {
                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Password change was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.")
                        }
                        <input type="hidden" id="buttonid" name="buttonid" value="@buttonid2" />
                        <div>
                            <fieldset>
                                <legend>Account Information</legend>
                                <div class="editor-label">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OldPassword)
                                </div>
                                <div class="editor-field">
                                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.OldPassword)
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.OldPassword)

                                </div>
                                <div class="editor-label">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NewPassword)
                                </div>
                                <div class="editor-field">
                                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.NewPassword)
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.NewPassword)
                                </div>
                                <div class="editor-label">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
                                </div>
                                <div class="editor-field">
                                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
                                </div>
                                <p>
                                    <input type="submit" value="Change Password" class="btn btn-default" />
                                    <a class="close-profile-Password" id="cancelBtn"  href="">Cancel</a>
                                </p>
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
            @if (User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
            {
            <div style="clear: both; padding: 20px 0 10px 0">
                @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "ClientDetails", "Client", null, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
            </div>
            }
            else if (User.IsInRole("Employer"))
            {
                <div style="clear: both; padding: 20px 0 10px 0">
                @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "CustomerIndex", "Customer", null, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
            </div>
            }
            else
            {
                <div style="clear: both; padding: 20px 0 10px 0">
                @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "WorkerIndex", "Worker", null, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
            </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is my js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $("#accordion").accordion({
            heightStyle: "content",
            collapsible: true,
            active: false,
            autoHeight: false,
            animated: false


        });
        $("#editUserName").validationEngine();
        var buttonid = $("#buttonid");
                $("#changeUserForm").validationEngine();

        $("#open-profile-Username").click(function (e) {
            $('#open-profile-Username').attr("hidden", true);
            $('#open-profile-Password').attr("hidden", false);
            $('#editUserName').validationEngine('hide');


        });
        $("#open-profile-Password").click(function (e) {



            $('#NewPassword').attr("value", "");
            $('#OldPassword').attr("value", "");
            $('#ConfirmPassword').attr("value", "");
            $('#changeUserForm').validationEngine('hide');
            $('#open-profile-Password').attr("hidden", true);
            $('#open-profile-Username').attr("hidden", false);


        });

    });
</script>
```

This is my layout file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/normalize.css")" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo.common.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo.metro.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/validationEngine.jquery.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    @*<link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />*@
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/colorbox.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo.all.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic|Roboto+Condensed:400,700'
        rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validationEngine.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validationEngine-en.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.colorbox.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="@Url.Content("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.14&key=AIzaSyD_b-Iyp4MpC2fvDSgtFVPyznZJCxIeUNw&sensor=false")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="../../Content/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../../Content/css/flexslider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../../Content/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../../Content/css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

there.. Im using asp.net mvc.. thanks ...

Comment: http://jquery.com/browser-support/

Comment: im using jquery-1.8.3

Comment: @RobG i edited my question and indicate there that im using jquery-1.8.3. thanks

Comment: First off, why not check the line-number of the error, or a call-stack? Maybe show you layout file as well.

Comment: sir @awexfwex thanks... i already include the layout file..

Comment: it just says the error in line 2